# iteratively calculating an exponentially weighted moving average using dplyr

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like:

```
  cat1 cat2         d
1    A    C 0.6445386
2    B    D 0.1831454
3    A    C 0.5093117
4    A    D 0.3516816
5    B    C 0.2547064
6    A    D 0.3209060
```

And I want to calculate the exponentially weighted moving average by cat1 and cat2.

Using an initial value of zero, this would be something like:

```
table %>% 
          group_by(cat1,cat2) %>% 
          arrange(cat1,cat2) %>% 
          mutate(ema = (1-lambda)*ema+lambda*lag(ema,1,default=0)
```

But this returns an error:

```
Error in (1 - lambda) * ema + lambda * lag(ema, 1, default = 0) : 
  object 'ema' not found
```

How can I fix this?  Is it not possible to reference a previous iteration using dplyr?

Comment: Try the EMA function in the TTR package.

Comment: I don't think its possible to refer a previous iteration in dplyr

Answer (score 0):

When you are referencing `ema` for the first time its not initialized, so there is no object named `ema`

in your code 
mutate(**ema** = (1-lambda) * **ema**+lambda * lag(ema,1,default=0)

that bold `ema` is self referencing, probably the formula you are looking for is this: `(1-lambda)*d + lambda*lag(ema)`, so I used this in the solution

```
library(dplyr)
table <- data.frame(cat1 = c("A","B","A","A","B","A"),
                    cat2 = c("C","D","C","D","C","D"),
                    d = c(0.1831454, 0.5093117, 0.3516816 ,0.2547064 ,0.3209060,0.6445386))

lambda <- 0.55
table$ema <- NA
table$ema[1] <- table$d[1]

table %>% 
  group_by(cat1,cat2) %>% 
  arrange(cat1,cat2)

for(i in (2:dim(table)[1])){
  table$ema[i] <- table$d[i]*(1-lambda) + lambda*(table$ema[i-1])
}
```

is this what you are looking for ?

**EDIT:** Changed the code

Comment: When I run your code I get table$ema[1]=.45, and table$ema=NA for all other indices - this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Yeah, I was in a hurry yesterday, sorry about that. So here the problem is again we are referring to a NA ema, I ve searched around a bit but couldnt find a pipe method to do this. and one more thing, the EMA formula that you use is self referencing, the correct formula might be this `(1-lambda)*d+lambda*lag(ema)`, so I will be using this formula in my solution

Comment: Yes - i solved it that same way, but was looking for an alternative using mutate/dplyr.  I don't think your solution works for my specific case because there are group by variables so you need to reset the seed.  No worries though, I already wrote that in, will post my solution later.